# Automation in R: how to apply a single process to different columns

Tags: r

this is a simple question, but I am not proficient in automation in R.
So I'm asking this.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
x<-c(2,5,1,1,23,1,23,51,36,85,24,1,645,945,
2,8,124,4,35,6,71,45,1,5,12,52,764,8,6,234,
98,234,456,6,1,452,32,176,75,31)
x<-matrix(x,ncol=5)
x<-data.frame(x)
names(x)<-c("car","bike","bus","train","walk")
```

so in the end you'd get a dataframe like this:

```
car    bike    bus    train    walk
 2      36     124     12      456
 5      85       4     52        6
 1      24      35    764        1
 1       1       6      8      452
23     645      71      6       32
 1     945      45    234      176
23       2       1     98       75
51       8       5    234       31
```

So I want to calculate the growth of each transportation:

```
x$car_growth<-((diff(x$car)/x$car)*100)
```

however, the first value will be empty, so I need to arrange it such that it will go into the right row. To do that, I make a new df

```
k<-data.frame(seq(from=1,to=8)
names(k)<-c("seq")
k2<-data.frame(x$car_growth)
k2$seq<-seq(from=2, to=9)
k3<-merge(k2, k, by="seq", all=TRUE)
k3<-k3[1:8,]
x2<-cbind(x,k3)
x2$seq<-NULL
```

So in the end you will get something like this

```
car    bike    bus    train    walk   car_growth
 2      36     124     12      456       NA
 5      85       4     52        6      150
 1      24      35    764        1     -400
 1       1       6      8      452        0
23     645      71      6       32     2200 
 1     945      45    234      176    -2200
23       2       1     98       75     2200
51       8       5    234       31     48.7
```

These are only 1 process for item car.

I wanna repeat this for bike, bus, train, and walk.

Of course the original data that I have is MUCHHH bigger and longer than this. I just want to learn how to automate all these processes into a few lines short script like excel VBA

Thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

With base R you could do, in case you agree that when car drops from 5 to 1 it decreases with 80%, not with 400%:

```
x <- cbind(x,
rbind(NA,
apply(x, 2, function(i) diff(i) / i[-8] * 100)
))

colnames(x)[6:10] <- paste0(colnames(x[6:10]), "_growth")

  car bike bus train walk car_growth bike_growth bus_growth train_growth
1   2   36 124    12  456         NA          NA         NA           NA
2   5   85   4    52    6  150.00000   136.11111  -96.77419    333.33333
3   1   24  35   764    1  -80.00000   -71.76471  775.00000   1369.23077
4   1    1   6     8  452    0.00000   -95.83333  -82.85714    -98.95288
5  23  645  71     6   32 2200.00000 64400.00000 1083.33333    -25.00000
6   1  945  45   234  176  -95.65217    46.51163  -36.61972   3800.00000
7  23    2   1    98   75 2200.00000   -99.78836  -97.77778    -58.11966
8  51    8   5   234   31  121.73913   300.00000  400.00000    138.77551
  walk_growth
1          NA
2   -98.68421
3   -83.33333
4 45100.00000
5   -92.92035
6   450.00000
7   -57.38636
8   -58.66667
```

Or with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(c(NA, diff(.)) / lag(.) * 100)) %>% 
  bind_cols(x, .) %>% 
  rename_at(vars(ends_with("1")), function(i) gsub("1", "_growth", i))
```

Comment: looks promising. I'll try this later

Answer (score 0):

this should do it

```
library(dplyr)
x<-c(2,5,1,1,23,1,23,51,36,85,24,1,645,945,
     2,8,124,4,35,6,71,45,1,5,12,52,764,8,6,234,
     98,234,456,6,1,452,32,176,75,31)
x<-matrix(x,ncol=5)
x<-data.frame(x)
names(x)<-c("car","bike","bus","train","walk")
```

give your growth function a name

```
get_growth <- function(column)(diff(column)/column)*100
```

use `mutate_all` to map the function over all columns and append "growth" to the name. I use `lag` the shift the result down one row.

```
mutate_all(x,funs(growth = lag(get_growth(.))))
```

hope this helps!!

Comment: Since you're only using `dplyr` here, it may be more instructive to just load that.

Comment: @Axeman your right I changed that